# ValueError: Field 'id'

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

When I POST new email i send this request, sender and receiver should represent registered users...
i get this error

ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got '<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x10291f410>'.

I try to delete the migrations and the db.sqlite3 file several times, and run makemigrations & migrate commend but it didn't work.

I'm new to Django...So so sorry if i'm not in the right direction at all.

I would appreciate any help, thanks

```
    {            
        "sender": "test1@gmail.com",
        "receiver": "test2@gmail.com",
        "subject": "Hello",
        "message": "bbaa aaafff jjjj fslskjf adjfjfj dkdklfwl lfewjro fjklsfjl dddkkc 
        "unread": true
    }
```

**models.py**

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        email = self.normalize_email(email)

        user = self.model(
            email=email,
            **extra_fields
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", True)

        # is_staff -> controls whether the user is allowed to log in to the admin interface.
        if extra_fields.get("is_staff") is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser has to have is_staff attribute set to True.")

        # is_superuser -> have access to create, edit, and delete any object (models).
        if extra_fields.get("is_superuser") is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser has to have is_superuser attribute set to True.")

        return self.create_user(email=email, password=password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=80, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    objects = CustomUserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


class Email(models.Model):

    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sender", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="receiver", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = models.TextField()
    unread = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.subject
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from core.models import Email, User
from rest_framework.validators import ValidationError
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token


class SignUpSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=80)
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=8, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password']

    def validate(self, attrs):
        email = User.objects.filter(email=attrs["email"]).exists()
        if email:
            raise ValidationError('Email has already exist.')

        return super().validate(attrs)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop("password")
        user = super().create(validated_data)
        user.set_password(password)

        user.save()
        Token.objects.create(user=user)
        return user


class EmailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sender = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='email')

    receiver = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='email')

    class Meta:
        model = Email
        fields = ['id', "sender", "receiver", "subject", "message", "unread", "created_at"]


class CurrentUserEmailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    emails = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'email']
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.request import Request
from rest_framework import status, generics, mixins
from core.models import Email
from core.serializers import EmailSerializer, SignUpSerializer
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny, IsAuthenticated
from core.tokens import create_jwt_pair_for_user


class APIEntryPoint(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def get(self, request: Request):
        response = {
            "message": "Abra, Welcome to Messaging System API."
        }
        return Response(data=response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


class SignUpView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = SignUpSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request: Request):
        data = request.data

        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            response = {
                "message": "User created Successfully!",
                "data": serializer.data
            }
            return Response(data=response, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        response = {
            "message": "An error occurred while creating new user.",
            "data": serializer.errors
        }
        return Response(data=response, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class LoginView(APIView):

    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request: Request):
        email = request.data.get("email")
        password = request.data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            tokens = create_jwt_pair_for_user(user)
            response = {
                "message": "User login successfully.",
                "tokens": tokens
            }
            return Response(data=response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            response = {
                "message": "Invalid email or password.",
            }
            return Response(data=response, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

    def get(self, request: Request):
        content = {
            "user": str(request.user),
            "auth": str(request.auth),
        }
        return Response(data=content, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


class EmailsView(generics.GenericAPIView, mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin):
    """
    View for create and listing emails
    """
    serializer_class = EmailSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    queryset = Email.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        sender = self.request.user
        serializer.save(sender=sender)

        return super().perform_create(serializer)

    def get(self, request: Request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request: Request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)


class EmailView(generics.GenericAPIView,
                mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.UpdateModelMixin, mixins.DestroyModelMixin):
    serializer_class = EmailSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    queryset = Email.objects.all()

    def get(self, request: Request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def put(self, request: Request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, request: Request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.APIEntryPoint.as_view(), name="entry_point"),
    # User
    path("users/auth/register/", views.SignUpView.as_view(), name="register"),
    path("users/auth/login/", views.LoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
    # User -> JWT
    path("users/auth/jwt/create/", TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name="jwt_create"),
    path("users/auth/jwt/refresh/", TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name="token_refresh"),
    path("users/auth/jwt/verify/", TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name="token_verify"),
    # Email
    path("emails/", views.EmailsView.as_view(), name="emails"),
    path("email/<int:pk>/", views.EmailView.as_view(), name="email"),

]
```